# Document Library marked as catalog can't be crawled by Search Engine

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, cross-site-publishing

I have created a new Site Collection in SharePoint Online.  I've turned on Cross Site Publishing for the Site Collection.  When I go into Library Settings --> Catalog Settings, I'm enabling the Library as a catalog.

When I go back to Catalog Settings, I'm getting a message under Search Information:

> It is not possible to retrieve crawl information as the system is
>   configured in a way that limits access to this information.

I've gone to the Advanced Settings page, confirmed the library should appear in search results and clicked re-index Document Library, but am still getting this message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  There must be at least one document present in a Document Library for Search Features to activate.